# Understanding execution flow of Clojure code

Tags: clojure

I’m learning Clojure now, I’m coming from imperative programming, so I have problems understanding execution flow of that code:

```
(defn chop-chop [coll]

  (let [x (partition-by identity coll)]

    (map list (map (comp str first) x)

                (map count x))))

=> (chop-chop "aaaabbbcca")

=> (("a" 4) ("b" 3) ("c" 2) ("a" 1))
```

I understand that we:

1. create here function chop-chop with parameter coll
2. then we apply function partition-by for coll, but I’m not sure what identity is
3. next we bound result of previous operation to x
4. but I can’t understand the next lines of code:

```
(map list (map (comp str first) x)
    (map count x))))
```

Could someone explain to me step-by-step execution flow of that program?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you notice words like "identity" that you don't know, then this page will help a lot: https://clojure.github.io/clojure/index.html is the Clojure function index.

Comment: @BipedPhill do you prefer that to ClojureDocs? https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identity

Comment: @AaronBell I like to make sure people who have not yet found "the manual" learn where to find the real thing (clojure.org and clojure.github.io).  There's room for two tabs in every browser :-)

Comment: `(for [x (partition-by identity "aaaabbbcca")] [(first x) (count x)])`

Comment: `(map (juxt first count) (partition-by identity "aaaabbbcca"))`

Answer (score 5):

### The jist

This example:

1. Takes a collection (in this case, a string)
2. Gets the groups of repeating letters
3. Maps over the groups to get the representative letter
4. Maps over the groups to get the count of each group
5. Maps over #3 and #4 to get a key-value tuple, the letter and the number of times it repeats (for this instance, not all time).

### The jist+

On your four bullets:

1. Yup, it's a single-arity function defined with the `defn` macro
2. Yup, and `identity` returns the argument

```
;; Possible values: 1, :a, #(+ 1 2), {:a [1 2]}
(identity 1) ;;=> 1
(identity :a) ;;=> :a
(identity #(+ 1 2)) ;;=> #function[boop.core/eval7764/fn--7765]
(identity {:a [1 2]}) ;;=> {:a [1 2]}

(partition-by identity "aaaabbbcca") ;;=> (\a \a \a \a) (\b \b \b) (\c \c) (\a))
```

Just in case you don't understand partition-by, it creates a new group each time the value of the function changes. `#(< 3 %)` will be `false` for `1`, `2`. Because the results are identical, they're grouped together. `3` `4` `5` will have the same result, so they'll be grouped together.

```
;; f
;; =
;; number?

;; coll
;; [1 2 3 4 5]
;; [:a :b '(:Yo) 3]

;; f1 coll1
(partition-by #(= 3 %) [1 2 3 4 5]) ;;=> ((1 2) (3) (4 5))
;; f1 coll2
(partition-by #(= 3 %) [:a :b '(:Yo) 3]) ;;=> ((:a :b (:Yo)) (3))
;; f2 coll1
(partition-by number? [1 2 3 4 5]) ;;=> ((1 2 3 4 5))
;; f2 coll2
(partition-by number? [:a :b '(:Yo) 3]) ;;=> ((:a :b (:Yo)) (3))
```

3. Yes, you bind the previous operation to `x`. This example **maps two maps**, so *it would've been clearer if they bound the two maps to variables*:

```
(defn chop-chop [coll]

  (let [x (partition-by identity coll)
        ;; Could bind the two maps here
        first-letter-map (map (comp str first) x)
        repeating-letter-count (map count x)]
    ;; a map of maps
    (map list first-letter-map repeating-letter-count)))

(chop-chop "aaaabbbcca") ;;=> (("a" 4) ("b" 3) ("c" 2) ("a" 1))
```

4. On the last bit of code:

Maps can map over one *or more* collections.

Here's one collection per map:

```
;; maps
;; (map (comp str first) x)
;; (map count x)

;; coll
;; [["woo" "yes"] ["hello" "world"]]
;; ((\a \a \a \a) (\b \b \b) (\c \c) (\a)), the result of (partition-by identity "aaaabbbcca")

;; m1 c1
(map (comp str first) [["woo" "yes"] ["hello" "world"]]) ;;=> ("woo" "hello")
;; m1 c2
(map (comp str first) '((\a \a \a \a) (\b \b \b) (\c \c) (\a))) ;;=> ("a" "b" "c" "a")
;; m2 c1
(map count [["woo" "yes"] ["hello" "world"]]) ;;=> (2 2)
;; m2 c2
(map count '((\a \a \a \a) (\b \b \b) (\c \c) (\a))) ;;=> (4 3 2 1)
```

Here's two collections per map:

```
;; function
;; #(str (first %1) (first %2))
;; #(list (count %1) (count %2))

;; same colls, but passed in at the same time
;; [["woo" "yes"] ["hello" "world"]]
;; ((\a \a \a \a) (\b \b \b) (\c \c) (\a)) 

(def c1 [["woo" "yes"] ["hello" "world"]])
(def c2 '((\a \a \a \a) (\b \b \b) (\c \c) (\a)))

(map #(str (first %1) (first %2)) c1 c2) ;;=> ("wooa" "hellob")
(map #(list (count %1) (count %2)) c2 c1) ;;=> ((4 2) (3 2))
```

You should also understand `comp`:

```
;; comp vs. personall const
;; (comp str first)
;; #(str (first %))

;; seq
;; [\a "Wow"]
;; [132 :a]

;; c1 s1
((comp str first) [\a "Wow"]) ;;=> "a"
;; c2 s1
(#(str (first %)) [\a "Wow"]) ;;=> "a"
;; c1 s2
((comp str first) [132 :a]) ;;=> "132"
;; c2 s2
(#(str (first %)) [132 :a]) ;;=> "132"
```

Welcome to the Clojure community!

Comment: Thank you very much for such clear and detailed explanation! I'll try my best to learn Clojure!

Answer (score 4):

`partition-by` applies function `identity` for each value in `col`, and it splits `col` each time it returns a new value.
For example:

```
user=> (partition-by #(= 3 %) [1 2 3 4 5])
((1 2) (3) (4 5))
```

It applies partition with the function (= 3 %), so it splits the col in 3 parts, `(1 2)` are false `(3)` is true and `(4 5)` is false.
You are using `identity` as function, aa function that returns its argument.
 `(partition-by identity  "aaaabbbcca")` returns `((\a \a \a \a) (\b \b \b) (\c \c) (\a))`.

Next you are doing `(map count x)`, so you are counting each list of your `x`, returning: `(4 3 2 1)`.
`(map (comp str first) x)` returns you a string with first character of each list in `x`: `("a" "b" "c" "a")`.

Finally you are doing:

```
 (map list '("a" "b" "c" "a") 
                '(4 3 2 1))))
```

And that creates a list combining the two lists:
For example, with the first element of each list makes:
`(list "a" 4)-> ("a" 4)`
Doing this with the four elements:

```
 (("a" 4) ("b" 3) ("c" 2) ("a" 1))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for clear explanation!